# Simple IUserStore, IUserPasswordStore implementation gives Invalid login attempt

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-core-2.2

I am experimenting with Aspnet Core 2.2 and have replaced the standard `IdentityUser` with my `MyIdentityUser`. When I try to log on I get "Invalid login attempt."

What is it I have missed to implement to allow me to log in?

---

The `ConfigureServices` method sets up Identity with my `MyIdentiyUser` and `MyIUserStore` like so:

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<MyIdentityUser>()
    .AddDefaultUI(UIFramework.Bootstrap4)
    .AddUserStore<MyUserStore>();
```

By implementing all `IUserStore` and `IUserPasswordStore` methods as sparingly as possbile (I started with every method throwing `NotImplementedException` and then implementing the ones that were called) I got to this:

```
public class MyUserStore : IUserStore<MyIdentityUser>, IUserPasswordStore<MyIdentityUser>
{
    public void Dispose() { }

    public Task<MyIdentityUser> FindByNameAsync(string normalizedUserName, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var ret = new MyIdentityUser
        {
            Id = "1",
            UserName = normalizedUserName
        };
        return Task.FromResult(ret);
    }

    public Task<string> GetUserIdAsync(MyIdentityUser user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(user.UserName);
    }

    public Task<string> GetPasswordHashAsync(MyIdentityUser user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.FromResult("asdf");
    }
    ... the rest of the methods throws exception.
}
```

For the sake of being complete here is my `MyIdentityUser`

```
public class MyIdentityUser
{
    public string Id {get;set;}
    public string UserName {get;set}
}
```

and start of `_LoginPartial.cshtml`

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@inject SignInManager<MyIdentityUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<MyIdentityUser> UserManager
```

Comment: Cause you return an empty hash? an empty password do not generate an empty hash

Comment: @Tseng I updated and tested with a hash of "asdf". Same result.

Comment: again, unless you generate the algorithm with the exact same password hasher, it will be different than what you are checking. See for some background information https://andrewlock.net/exploring-the-asp-net-core-identity-passwordhasher/ (may be slightly different now, linked article is 2 years old)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were returning an empty string as hash

```
public Task<string> GetPasswordHashAsync(MyIdentityUser user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    return Task.FromResult(string.Empty);
}
```

But even an empty password, do not results in an empty hash string. On top of that, there are different algorithms used (which can be configured in Startup.cs, when adding Identity).

You will have to return a real, calculated hash from a specific password if you want it succeed, otherwise it will recognized the entered password returns a different hash then the "stored" one and will cause a failure in login.

Just because you are faking/implementing the user store do not mean the hash validations won't be performed.

```
public Task<string> GetPasswordHashAsync(MyIdentityUser user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var hash = new PasswordHasher<MyIdentityUser>().HashPassword(user, "asdf");
    return Task.FromResult(hash)
}
```

Will do, though beware that if you change the password hash algorithm it may fail, since you are `new`ing it, which means it uses the default options for password hashing.

Comment: You could just take an instance of `IPasswordHasher<MyIdentityUser>` through DI to save the worry expressed in your last statement.

Comment: @KirkLarkin Would you care to explain how to get a `IPasswordHasher<MyIdentityUser>` instance through dependency injection? I am a seasoned developer but new to AspnetCore.

Comment: Just add a constructor parameter of `IPasswordHasher<MyIdentityUser>`, assign the incoming argument to a field of your store and then use that in your `GetPasswordHashAsync` implementation.